# AppleScript to find lost Outlook mail and archive them

Tags: email, ms-office

I'm working with a friend who uses Outlook on his Mac (I don't know why). He has several folders that were stored on his computer through Outlook that are now missing. If I run a search on his computer, I can pull up specific emails that were in the folders, but I cannot find the actual folders.

The only thing I can do at this point is try to write an apple script that will look for emails based on a certain criteria and archive them.

How can I go about doing this? 
Can I get the system to automatically run this when on boot-up?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook mails are not saved individually as files- under normal uses!

They are  part of the Outlook database located here:

Outlook 2011 (Mac version) saves all data in:

```
~/Documents/Microsoft User data/Main identity
```

Database: Microsoft Outlook Database

or the respective Backup folder (if you Backed up emails)

You can open one of those and find your emails there.

An Automator script would not do much here, since using Outlook is faster and better to find emails in Outlook database.